# How to resize a shape using CellsSRC?

Tags: vba, visio

I'd like to resize a shape (a line to be specific), I know it's possible to move a line with cellsSRC using the following line :

```
element.CellsSRC(visSectionObject, visRowXFormOut, visXFormBeginX).result("in") = 0.1
```

but is it possible to change the size of a line using cellsSRC ? and how to do so ? Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by 'change the size of a line', as a line has begin and end points in Visio, and are considered one dimensional. There's a thickness, which is controlled separately.

You can use CellsU to control the begin and end points, which is just easier than knowing the SRC address.  So there are four cells: BeginX, BeginY, EndX, EndY, which specify the x and y coordinates of the begin and end points.

So to move the begin point to 1,2:

```
 element.cellsU("BeginX").formula = "1"
 element.cellsu("BeginY").formula = "2"
```